# Download a file from Controller in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, download, file

I create a Product View Tab and fill this with some PDF download links. Now link in Magento 1.9 I create a controller to prepare the download response.

I don't find any solution to download a file from VAR folder.

In Magento 1.9 I simply call the function `$this->_prepareDownloadResponse( ... )`

How I do this in Magento 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

For this `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory` is your friend.

You can look into this class for more reference

`\Magento\OfflineShipping\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\ExportTablerates`

```
 public function execute()
    {
        $fileName = 'tablerates.csv';
        /** @var $gridBlock \Magento\OfflineShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Carrier\Tablerate\Grid */
        $gridBlock = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\OfflineShipping\Block\Adminhtml\Carrier\Tablerate\Grid'
        );
        $website = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'));
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('conditionName')) {
            $conditionName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('conditionName');
        } else {
            $conditionName = $website->getConfig('carriers/tablerate/condition_name');
        }
        $gridBlock->setWebsiteId($website->getId())->setConditionName($conditionName);
        $content = $gridBlock->getCsvFile();
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($fileName, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
    }
```

Now, I think you can easily get an Idea how to crack your requirement :)